# why this happen in type conversion?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am new to springMVC ,today i write a DateConverter
like this

```
public class DateConverter implements Converter<String,Date>{

    private String formatStr = "";

    public DateConverter(String fomatStr) {
        this.formatStr = formatStr;
    }

    public Date convert(String source) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = null;
        Date date = null;
        try {
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr);
            date = sdf.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return date;

    }
}
```

then i write a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/converterTest") 
public void testConverter(Date date){
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

congfigure it to applicationContext,i am sure the DateConverter has been initialized correctly,when i test my converter with

```
http://localhost:8080/petStore/converterTest?date=2011-02-22

the browser says:
HTTP Status 400 -
type Status report
message
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

somebody could help me with it? thanks in advance

Comment: If you change the controller method to receive a `String` instead of a `Date`, does it work?

Comment: of course that's ok ,but what i want is to change the string to Date,so i write the converter

Comment: What about add @RequestParam("date") to testConverter(Date date)?

Comment: @kevin: how did you config your conversion service?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your converter. You misspelled the constructor param, so the assignment has no effect.  Instead of:

```
public DateConverter(String fomatStr) {
    this.formatStr = formatStr;
}
```

try:

```
public DateConverter(String formatStr) {
    this.formatStr = formatStr;
}
```

There may be other issues, but at a minimum you'll want to fix that.  I'm assuming you are using `yyyy-MM-dd` for your date format?